# Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. For $f(x) = ax+b$, under what conditions on $a$ and $b$ is $f$ a bijection?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation, elementary-functions

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. 
Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(x) = ax+b$.

Under what conditions on $a$ and $b$ is $f$ a bijection?

---

Here I'm looking at two cases: if $a=0$, and if $a\neq 0$.

Case 1:

If $a=0, f(x) = b$.

Thus $f = \{(0,b)\}$.

Let us test whether this function is injective and/or surjective.

For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there is no unique $y \in \mathbb{R}$ since $f(x) = b$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

However, $b$ is only one point in the infinite set, $\mathbb{R}$. So $\exists y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \neq y.$

So the function is neither injective nor surjective, and as such not bijective.

---

Case 2:

If $a \neq 0$, then $f(x) = ax + b$.

Thus $f = \{(x_1, ax_1+b), (x_2,ax_2+b),(x_3,ax_3+b),...\}$

Let us test whether this function is injective and/or surjective.

Assume $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$.

$\implies ax_1+b = ax_2+b$

$\implies ax_1 = ax_2$

$\implies x_1 = x_2$, so $f$ is injective.

Now we check for surjectivity.

If $x \in \mathbb{R} \land a \neq 0$, we can choose an $x = \frac{y-b}{a}$

$f(x) = a(\frac{y-b}{a})+b$

$\implies f(x) = (y-b)+b$

$\implies f(x) = y$, so $f$ is surjective.

Therefore $f$ is bijective $\iff a \neq 0$.

---

I am a little confused on the first case. For some reason my brain wants to tell me that $f$ is actually surjective. I'm visualizing a straight line going in both directions on a plot. Wouldn't that cover everything? Why is it a point and not an infinite line that maps all of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: For a=0, your function $f(x)=b$ is a horizontal line, meaning it only takes on a single $y$-value. So, while you can plug in any value $x\in\mathbb{R}$, you will only ever get $b$ as an output, thus it's not surjective as it cannot take on all values of $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Two about case 1: When proving injectivity we want to prove that if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ that $x_1=x_2$.  You just wrote "$b=b$ therefore injective" but this is incorrect.  $b=b$ does not imply that $x_1=x_2$.  In fact, notice that $f(1)=f(2)$ but $1\neq 2$, providing a counterexample to your claim.  Secondly, about surjectivity, we wish to show that all possibly $y$ values have a preimage, i.e. that all heights on the graph are realized at some point.  As mentioned, only one height is ever realized, and so it is not surjective.  There is no value of $x$ such that $f(x)=b+1$

Comment: Oh I see it now. When I thought it of as an infinite line, I forgot that it is only horizontal (so it only ever touched one $y$-value). 

So in that case, $f$ is neither injective, nor surjective.

Comment: Yes.  Recognize also why your proof for case two does not work for case 1.  $ax_1=ax_2\Rightarrow x_1=x_2$ fails when $a$ is able to be zero.  ($0\cdot 1=0\cdot 2=0$ but $1\neq 2$).  Further $\frac{y-b}{a}$ does not exist when $a=0$ due to a division by zero error.

Comment: Yes, but in that second case we're looking specifically at $a \neq 0$ so such an instance will never happen