# For $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ given by $f(x)=ax+b$, for what $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ is $f$ a bijection?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I asked a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814087/let-a-b-in-mathbbr-for-fx-axb-under-what-conditions-on-a-and).
This question has different parameters however as you can see.

For $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ given by $f(x)=ax+b$, for what $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ is $f$ a bijection?

---

Observe the case where $a = 1$ and $b = 0$.

Then $f(x) = x$.

Assuming $f(x_1) = f(x_2) $,

$\implies x_1 = x_2$, so $f$ is injective.

For $f(x) = y \in \mathbb{N}$, choose $x = y$ such that

$f(x) = y$, so $f$ is surjective.

Therefore $f$ is bijective when $a=1$ and $b=0$.

---

What are the other cases here and how do I disprove them? Please be careful not to give too much away.

Intuitively, $a \leq 0, b= 0$ doesn't work because $f(x) = -ax\leq0$, $\forall x\in \mathbb{N}$, and $f(x) \in \mathbb{N}$ has to be positive since $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$.

Also, if both $a,b=0$, then $f(x) = 0$ which is also not in the natural numbers, so that's moot.

If $a > 1$ then the function will not map to all of $\mathbb{N}$. I'm buying this intuitively, since the output would look something like

$f = \{(1,1a), (2,2a), (3,3a), ...\}$ and for $a > 1, 1a \neq 1, 2a\neq 2$ and so on. That is to say, the natural numbers will not be mapped to. I don't really know how best to actually say this in a proof.

Similarly, if $b > 0$, then at least $b$ values would not be mapped to since the entire "graph" so to speak would be shifted up.

These are all things I don't really know how to say even though I think I understand them conceptually. Can someone help me break it down?

Answer (score 2):

This might help.

A function is a bijection if and only if it has an inverse.

First you can wonder: if $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ prescribed by $x\mapsto ax+b$ has an inverse $g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ then how is $g$ prescribed?

The answer to that is: $$x\mapsto\frac{x-b}{a}$$

The **real question** can now be worded as: under what conditions on $a,b$ is this indeed a legitimate prescription of a function $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$?

E.g. it is immediate that $a=0$ is not allowed. Also $a=2$ is not because it would lead to values not in $\mathbb N$.

Comment: This statement confuses me because I thought injectivity was the sufficient condition for a function to have an inverse

Comment: @J.S.R. Injectivity is all that's needed for a function $f$ to have an inverse $g$ *defined on the range of $f$*.  But here the inverse is expected to be defined on all of $\mathbb N$, so $f$ also needs to be surjective (otherwise the inverse is only partially defined on $\mathbb N$).

Comment: That makes sense, I posted a question earlier about how a strictly injective function has an inverse whose domain is a proper subset of the codomain of the original function. A bijection's inverse would have the codomain equal the domain of the original function, correct?

Comment: That is correct, but is allready true by injectivity of $f$. More important is that  the inverse of a bijective $f:X\to Y$ will have $Y$ as its domain. This is not necessarily the case if $f$ is only injective. Formally if $f:X\to Y$ is injective with $A:=\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}$ and $A\neq Y$ then not function $f$ has an inverse, but the function $X\to A$ that is prescribed by $x\mapsto f(x)$ (wich is a bijection) has an inverse.

Comment: When you say $a=2$ is not allowed, do you also mean to say values greater than 1, or just that? My impression is that dividing by anything other than 1 would result in a fraction which is not in the natural numbers. But then again... doesn't this depend on $b$? :|

Comment: I only used $a=2$ as an example. To help you further: note that $\frac{2-b}{a}-\frac{1-b}{a}=\frac1{a}$. So if the inverse indeed exists then $\frac1{a}\in\mathbb N$. This excludes $a>1$. Also $a<1$ can be excluded on other grounds (can you find them?). So you end up with $a=1$ and now it is time to start looking at $b$. Good luck.